# Editing onclick condition

Tags: onclick, conditional-statements

I got this piece of code from a .tpl opencart category file, which makes plus and minus buttons add product quantity before dropping it to a cart. The problem is that there's not restriction for the minus button to go below zero which results in this:

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

```
<div class="cart-quantity"> 
<i onclick="$(this).next().val($(this).next().val()-1);$(this).parents('form').submit();" class="fa fa-minus"></i> 
<input class="qtypm" type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>" id="quantity_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"/>
<i onclick="$(this).prev().val(~~$(this).prev().val()+1);$(this).parents('form').submit();" class="fa fa-plus"></i>
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" />
</div>
```

Is there a way to improve this specific piece of code to block the minus button go below zero (or better 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through html attribute. Use the `min` and set it to `1`. Check the example below.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1">
```

Let me know if it solves your problem

/rjb